# ECLIPSE - Object Repository Program - NullPointerException Error Shown

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

[image]

Have below Selenium Program using Object Repository Library File but the same is failing and shows java.lang.NullPointerException. Have commented the specific syntax lines as "error". Also attached the error screenshot and config.property files.enter image description here. Have tried to identify the cause but could not. please clarify the cause of the failing and error message. [image]

```
package objectrepository;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import objectrepository.Lib_ChromeDriver;

public class OBRClass_2 {

@Test
public void launch_chrome() throws Exception{

Lib_ChromeDriver LCD = new Lib_ChromeDriver();// Lib_ChromeDriver is the Object Repository Library File 

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", LCD.Path());// error shown

WebDriver Snap = new ChromeDriver();

Snap.get(LCD.AppURL());


}
}
```

and:

```
// a Java Class containing Constructor & method and is saved as Library file.
// Constructor has will call the ObjectRepository File and 
// method will call the Call the ChromeDriver Location to Launch the same
// this Library Class can be called in Selenium program to launch the Chrome Driver 

package objectrepository;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Lib_ChromeDriver {

Properties Prop;

@Test
public void Lib_ChromeDriver() throws Exception{// Constructor calling the Object Repository File

File OB_File = new File("./Config/Config.property");
FileInputStream OB_FIS = new FileInputStream(OB_File);
Prop = new Properties();
Prop.load(OB_FIS);
}

public String Path() throws Exception{// method calling the ChromeDriver Path to Launch the same

String ChromePath = Prop.getProperty("ChromeDriver"); // error shown
return ChromePath;
}

public String AppURL() throws Exception{

String AppURL = Prop.getProperty("URL");
return AppURL;
}
}
```

Comment: `Prop` is `null`. Are you expecting it not to be `null`?

Comment: @badri - does my answer address your problem?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public void Lib_ChromeDriver()   // not a constructor
```

to

```
public Lib_ChromeDriver()       // is a constructor
```

the code you are calling is not in your constructor but in a method called `Lib_ChromeDriver`

In this case your code is calling the `default` constructor which does not have any code in it - therefore the variable `Props` is never set